# Updating the dataset into the database in C# .net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dataset

I am using a stored procedure to fetch the data from the database and populating the dataset with the output. I am trying to update some valued to the dataset that is populated.

Now how do i update the modified dataset to the database.

1) Should i update the database by looping through the dataset rows?
2) Will dataadapter.Update(dataset) will work in this case (data fetched using stored procedure) ?
3) which is the efficient way ?

I am using C# .NET 2.0 , SQL 2005

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

We built a solution using [Microsoft's Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203144.aspx). There is an [UpdateDataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd140060.aspx) method one can use to get the changes from a dataset into the database.

Answer (score 0):

From MSKB:
[How to update a database from a DataSet object by using Visual C# 2005 or Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307587)